# Fetch wordpress widgets/menu functions

Tags: wordpress, function, menu, widget, admin

im looking at codex but can't find a function to get the widgets and options from them. I would like the same functions for menu creation and manipulation.

Is there any function to get these values?

Answer (score 0):

All the [Widget API's](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) can be found in the Wordpress Codex.

The following api's will of use to you.

- [wp_get_sidebars_widgets](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_sidebars_widgets)
- [get_option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)

You will have better luck with specific codex questions at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com as opposed to SO.